# Convert .dat file into DataFrame when there is extra whitespace at the end of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am attempting to convert a data `.dat` file to a pandas dataframe. However, the `.dat` file contains extra whitespace at the end of each row, which creates an issue when reading the file as a dataframe.

The `.dat` file looks like this:

```
~ H H H H H H H H ~ ~
~ H H H H H H H H ~ ~
~ H H H H H H T T ~ ~
```

There are ten columns separated by white spaces, however there is also whitespace at the end of each row following the tenth column. Thus, when I view it as a pandas dataframe, I see 11 columns, the last of which is empty.

```
file = "mydata.dat"
colnames = ['res76','res77','res78','res79','res80','res81','res82','res83','res84','res85','res86']
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv(file,sep=' ', names=colnames)
df
```

Finally, the dataframe looks like this:

```
  res76 res77 res78 res79 res80 res81 res82 res83 res84 res85 res86
~  H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~      ~     NaN
~  H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~      ~     NaN
~  H     H     H     H     H     H     T     T     ~      ~     NaN
```

This, I assumed, was caused by the additional whitespace at the end of each row in the `.dat` file. However, I am not sure how to handle it using pandas. For instance, is it possible to omit the final whitespace? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: "There are ten columns separated by white spaces, however there is also whitespace at the end of each row following the tenth column. " I count 11 columns, and also 11 explicitly given names for columns. The reason you get an empty column at the end, as far as I can tell, is that Pandas is using the initial `~` on each line as an *index* rather than a column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 solutions to solve this problem with Pandas:

[`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
>>> pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', engine='python', names=colnames)

  res76 res77 res78 res79 res80 res81 res82 res83 res84 res85 res86
0     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
1     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
2     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     T     T     ~     ~
```

[`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
>>> pd.read_fwf(file, names=colnames)
  res76 res77 res78 res79 res80 res81 res82 res83 res84 res85 res86
0     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
1     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
2     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     T     T     ~     ~
```

[`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html):

```
>>> pd.read_table(file, sep=' ', names=colnames)
  res76 res77 res78 res79 res80 res81 res82 res83 res84 res85 res86
0     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
1     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
2     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     T     T     ~     ~
```

Comment: It makes sense that when `' '` is provided as a separator, Pandas sees an empty column at the end due to the space, and produces an empty column. But what's with the erratic behaviour when the number of `colnames` doesn't match that data? I tried testing with varying lengths and got some quite weird results. In particular, with insufficient names it seems to use leading data for the index, but sometimes truncates those resulting labels in ways I can't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Given your input format, it's better to use `read_fwf` instead of `read_csv`

```py
df = pd.read_fwf('mydata.dat', names=colnames)
```

```py
  res76 res77 res78 res79 res80 res81 res82 res83 res84 res85 res86
0     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
1     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     ~     ~
2     ~     H     H     H     H     H     H     T     T     ~     ~
```

Answer (score 1):

You may drop the last column from dataframe
`df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Or you may loops through file to remove trailing spaces (although not a clean solution).

```
parsed_file = open("parsed.dat", "w")

with open('mydata.dat') as mydatafile:
    for line in mydatafile:
        if line.endswith(" \n"): line = line.strip()
        parsed_file.write(line+"\n")
parsed_file.close()
```